# How to get all the values within multiple curly braces

Tags: c#, regex

How do I split the following into an array of strings within the curly braces?

i have tried regex, but the pattern is thrown off because of the new line

```cs
string script = @"{
ABC
DEF
}
{
GHI
LMN
}
{
QWE
ERT
}
"
```

return an array of with the new line intact

["ABC\nDEF", "GHI\nLMN", "QWE\nERT"]

Answer (score 0):

Hej i hope i got you right.
I know it is not the nices solution but it is something.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private enum Token
        {
            Open,
            Close,
            Char,
            UnKnowChar,
            Space,
            NewLine,
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"{
    ABC
    DEF
}
{
    GHI
    LMN
}
{
    QWE
    ERT
}
";
            var strings = Parse(text).ToArray();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string text)
        {
            var strings = new List<string>();
            var tokens = GetTokens(text);

            var opens = tokens.Select((token, index) => new {token, index})
                .Where(list => list.token == Token.Open).ToList();

            foreach (var open in opens)
            {
                var index = tokens.FindIndex(open.index, token => token == Token.Close);

                var substring = text.Substring(open.index + 1, index - open.index - 1);
                var trim = substring.Trim('\r', '\n', ' ');

                strings.Add(trim.Replace(' '.ToString(), string.Empty));
            }

            return strings;
        }

        private static List<Token> GetTokens(string text)
        {
            var tokens = new List<Token>();

            foreach (var _char in text)
                switch (_char)
                {
                    case ' ':
                        tokens.Add(Token.Space);
                        break;
                    case '\r':
                    case '\n':
                        tokens.Add(Token.NewLine);
                        break;
                    case '{':
                        tokens.Add(Token.Open);
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        tokens.Add(Token.Close);
                        break;
                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C':
                    case 'D':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F':
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H':
                    case 'I':
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L':
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O':
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S':
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V':
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z':
                        tokens.Add(Token.Char);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tokens.Add(Token.UnKnowChar);
                        break;
                }

            return tokens;
        }
    }
}
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's pretty much the same answer as `h3e`, except without adding the extra `Tokens` class and enum. We can just treat the string as an array of characters, get the indexes of all the opening and closing braces, and then grab the substrings from between them:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetItems(string text)
{
    var items = new List<string>();

    var openBraceIndexes = text.Select((chr, index) => new { chr = chr, index })
        .Where(item => item.chr == '{').ToList();

    var closeBraceIndexes = text.Select((chr, index) => new { chr, index })
        .Where(item => item.chr == '}').ToList();

    if (openBraceIndexes.Count != closeBraceIndexes.Count)
    {
        throw new FormatException("text contains an unequal number of open and close braces");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < openBraceIndexes.Count; i++)
    {
        var startIndex = openBraceIndexes[i].index + 1;
        var length = closeBraceIndexes[i].index - startIndex;
        items.Add(text.Substring(startIndex, length).Trim());
    }

    return items;
}
```